# Password enter by random captcha Image

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How to use selenium-webdriver to automate Password enter by random captcha Image like virtual keyboar and every time the position of image is change, so can't get unique id to identify element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try automating captcha by taking captcha image as WebElement, then getting the value of "alt" attribute and passing this value to a text field.

Comment: Yes that's true but i don't get "alt" attribute value because that is not set by developer and is third party API. If any other option then please suggest.. Thanks